# Excel 365 (2016) glacially slow to open workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel

On d-clicking an .xlsm file in Windows 10 File Explorer, Excel itself loads quickly, but it then takes around 5-10 seconds for the workbook to open.  Any file, even an empty one, even if I save as .xls.

Both Excel and the files are on C:, a fast SSD.

Other programs in the same MS Office package, such as Word 365, don't have this annoying flaw.

So frustrating compared to my old Excel 2000 with Win XP.

Answer (score 1):

Pleased to report I've found the cause. Following up a suggestion from the alt.comp.os,windows-10 newsgroup, I investigated add-ins. Turns out there are three types and this was a 'COM Add-in'.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/64zbyisg2cmca2o/ExcelAddIns-3types.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/77awp6lkhzcqryg/ExcelAddIns-2.jpg?dl=0

I have no idea why it got installed in Excel. Maybe a default option I missed when I re-installed my Space Navigator to use with Google Earth.

http://www.3dconnexion.co.uk/products/spacemouse/spacenavigator.html

But with that now unchecked, my worksheets open in a flash ;-)

-- 
Terry, East Grinstead, UK

Comment: links are broken now